# How does this function delete an element from a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

My instructor defined the function remove() as:

```
struct node
{
  node *next;
  int value;
}

int IntList::remove()
{
  node *victim = first;
  int result;

  if(isEmpty()) throw listIsEmpty();

  first = victim->next;
  result = victim->value;
  delete victim;
  return result;
}
```

Where `first` "points to the sequence of nodes representing this `IntList`."

If victim and first both point to the same thing, and we delete victim, doesn't this delete first as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If victim and first both point to the same thing, and we delete victim, doesn't this delete first as well?

At the time of deletion, they do not point to the same thing.

Basically what's happening here is that the the second node is becoming the first node, and then the old first node is being deleted.

Since `first = victim->next` before the delete, `first == victim` will never be the same unless `victim->next == victim` which should never happen in a linked list.

---

For a way simplified example, assume:

```
first is at address 0xDEAD (crazy address, but go with it)
first->next is at address 0xF00D
```

Then it goes down like this:

```
node *victim = first; //victim = 0xDEAD
first = victim->next; //first = 0xF00D, so first now = first->next
delete victim; //victim = 0xDEAD, so you deleted the original first
```

Comment: Oh, I see!  I was incorrectly assuming that first pointed to the entire linked list, and not just the first of many nodes in the linked list.  An elementary mistake- I'm still new to this! :)  Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Thinking about it: why can't result just be initialized to victim->value, as victim is initialized to first?

Comment: Because before you check isEmpty(), `victim` might be a null pointer, and that would cause the program to crash.  It could be declared as `int result = victim->value;` after the isEmpty() check though.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, It definitely does not delete the first node of your list.

because in 'int IntList::remove()' function it firstly just move ahead the first node, and then Delete the victim node.

*So, it'll delete victim only, and in your case, next node of the list will be the new first node. :)*